# PHP XPath Table elements disapearing

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I have just learned about XPath and I am wanting to read data from only certain columns in a table.

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php

$file_contents = file_get_contents('test.html');

$dom_document = new DOMDocument();

$dom_document->loadHTML($file_contents);

//use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

$elements = $dom_xpath->query("//tr[@class='rowstyle']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) 
    {
        echo $element->nodeValue . '<br />';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'none';
}

?>
```

Also a variation in the query because through my research I have seen lots of issues with nest table elements but it produces the same result:

```
$elements = $dom_xpath->query("//table[@class='tablestyle']/tbody/tr[@class='rowstyle']");
```

It does grab the row of data but it makes into a single string, combining all of the cells into one string and making the  tags disappear.

What I really want to do is separate those cells and grab the certain row number.

I am also curious on how to find out which version of XPath I have... My PHP version is 5.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not combining those cells... youre outputting the `nodeValue` which in this case is behaving like `innerHTML`. IF you want to work on the cells themselves the either use `childNodes` or a xpah query using the row as the context, then loop over the cells.

Example:

```
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

$elements = $dom_xpath->query("//tr[@class='rowstyle']");
foreach ($elements as $element) 
{
  foreach($element->childNodes as $cell) {
     echo $cell->nodeValue . '<br />';
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Also ran into a problem with invalid arguments so I suggest to future onlookers to use if($element->hasChildNodes()) around the inner foreach loop.